# Blender 2.78 video editor crash

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am using Blender 2.78, default startup file.  Repeatable crash on the following steps:

1. Open Blender
2. Switch to Video Editor window via dropdown box
3. Add a movie (with audio and video)
4. Select the audio track of the movie on the editing track
5. Blender crashes/quits

Anyone else ever use the video editor successfully?

Comment: does blender crash with a different file?

Comment: Best to [report it as a bug](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/) and provide access to the files that cause the crash, even if it is only the one file that causes it.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider are:
 Are you using an official release?
 Are you in the latest version or in an old verion? There is both Blender 2.78a and 2.78b now. I have been working in the video editor with 2.78b and have had no trouble. Try download and re-installing the latest verion. If it continues, try with a different video file. If the problem is fixed, then it means that your video file was damaged. It could also be your audio file... Hope this helps! :)

-Tovin